# Message: element not interactable Error While Sending Keys [search_bar.send_keys(course_name)] To Search Bar Of Youtube using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried Most of the solution of StackOverflow but didn't work for me
I am trying to send some course name to youtube search bar using selenium python it works fine before but now it gives this error while doing this
And search_bar.send_keys(course_name) works fine for other websites but not in YT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 766, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eel/__init__.py", line 257, in _process_message
        return_val = _exposed_functions[message['name']](*message['args'])
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/SmallTalk.py", line 72, in SingleQueryinputValue
        RecommendCourse.getUdacityCourse(str(val))
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/RecommendCourse.py", line 160, in getUdacityCourse
        getYoutubeCourse(course_name, driver)
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/RecommendCourse.py", line 98, in getYoutubeCourse
        search_bar.send_keys(course_name)
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
        return self._parent.execute(command, params)
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/home/sh4d0w/PycharmProjects/AutoMate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)

    2020-04-29T08:00:02Z <Greenlet at 0x7fd2089c67b8: _process_message({'call': 2.1877049007713376, 'name': 'SingleQueryi, <geventwebsocket.websocket.WebSocket object at 0x7)> failed with ElementNotInteractableException
```

Code sample

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("window-size=1200x600");
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=option)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
getYoutubeCourse(course_name, driver)
```

getYoutubeCourse() function body

```
def getYoutubeCourse(course_name, driver):
    time.sleep(2)

    search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
    search_bar.send_keys(course_name)

    search_bar_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')))
    search_bar_button.click()
    ......
```

then after this, the logic of scraping the youtube links is there
I also tried web driver wait and all, and my drivers are also up to date

Please help I am new in python and selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 3 elements found by xpath : `//*[@id="search"]`

You have to correct it to

```
//input[@id="search"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same problem. After hours filled with agony I finally found a solution.
While copying xpath (or any another id you are using to refer it) it points out to the entire search box container. After repeated trials and observations I found that a particular element (of the webpage which you can view in developer) with input mentioned was the one to be looked for:

```
<input id="search" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="search_query" tabindex="0" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" dir="ltr" class="ytd-searchbox" style="outline: none;">
```

The problem while copying xpath is that you get id of the container.

So use 'copy full xpath'. This will refer to the particular element within the container which can be given input.

full xpath for the input element of search box is:

```
'/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input'
```

You can use it like:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input')
search_bar.send_keys(song_name)
time.sleep(1)#You can skip this.
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

P.S. Excuse the terminology. I am also a beginner and this is my first answer.

Comment: Good one! You may shorten the xpath to `//ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def getYoutubeCourse(course_name, driver):
    time.sleep(2)

    search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="search"]')
    search_bar.send_keys(course_name)

    time.sleep(1)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who also got the same problem.
I tried full Xpath but it was still not working. And then, I plused [0] after xpath and it worked.

full xpath for the input element of search box is:

```
'/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input[0]'
```

And this if full source code

```
chrome_driver = '/Users/Downloads/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

search_bar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input')[0]

time.sleep(2)
search_bar.send_keys("black pink")

time.sleep(2)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Thank you