# Web automation error in python while running..i m using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I just started web automation and I can't figure out this error..
Code-

```
from selenium import webdriver

site = webdriver.Chrome()
site.get('https://www.youtube.com')
searchbar = site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
searchbar.click()
searchbar.send_keys('Fireproof')

searchButton = site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchButton.click()
```

[Error in cmd-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oqov.png)

Its opening the browser but not doing anything after that

Comment: Question has been answered before for youtube - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497221/message-element-not-interactable-error-while-sending-keys-search-bar-send-keys use //input[@id="search"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message: element not interactable Error While Sending Keys \[search\_bar.send\_keys(course\_name)\] To Search Bar Of Youtube using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497221/message-element-not-interactable-error-while-sending-keys-search-bar-send-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with XPath, user below code having updated XPath.

```
searchbar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="search"]')
searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
```